# Getting error while creating new Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-cli

I install AngularJs using the command `npm install -g angular-cli` and afterwards, when I was trying to create new project, I get the following error,

```
Cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'
```

What should I for resolve the error ?

Comment: Make sure you are using npm v3. Have you tried `npm install -g reflect-metadata`? Also take a look at this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2431

Answer (score 1):

I had to reintall nodeJS from their website and install `reflect-metadata` and `portfinder` using the following commands while being as superuser,

```
sudo npm install -g reflect-metadata
sudo npm install -g portfinder
```

Afterwards, I can create new project using the command,

```
ng new myProject
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `npm` by `npm install -g npm`.
If problem still exists try:

`npm i -g reflect-metadata`

Comment: After running the command  npm install -g npm, I get the follwoing error, 
-bash: npm: command not found

Comment: Try `curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` it will reinstall npm

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing node.js worked for me.